# Reading integers from a text file and adding them (C)

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C programming. I am currently preparing for an exam and I'm stuck on a program. The task is to read from a text file and make the sum of the integers inside it. The file also contains characters. I have tried this as a solution, and it is nearly correct, but it sometimes adds an integer too many times.

```
void calculate(char* file_name) {
    FILE* file;
    int sum = 0;
    int number;

    file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    char c;

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
    if (fscanf(file, "%d", &number)) {
        printf("The number is %i\n  ", number);
        sum = suma + number;
    }   
    }   
    fclose(file);
    printf("The sum is %i\n", sum);
}
```

For example, the text in the file is:

```
         asdd12 ddd15 dddgh51hh3
         3adb jk !!!*
```

The sum should be 84 for this file, but it prints 87. Is my method completely wrong or should I just change something in the code?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You are both `fgetc`ing and `fscanf`ing. Bad idea.

Comment: `char c;` should be `int c;` because `EOF` is not guaranteed to be representable by the `char` type.

Comment: @IanAbbott I would say it is guaranteed not to be represented :) (don't ask me where...)

Comment: If `fgetc` reads a digit, it has already gone by the time you call `fscanf` so you could read the wrong number. If you really want to use `fscanf`, you could check if `c` is a digit, and if so, call `ungetc` to push the digit back on the stream before you call `fscanf` to read it. You are only guaranteed to be able to push back one character before reading it again.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Where? `EOF` is only guaranteed to be an integer constant expression with type `int` and a negative value. C11 7.21.1p3. It is only guaranteed not to be represented on implementations where `char` is unsigned.

Comment: @IanAbbott As I said - don't ask me :) But apparently  if `EOF` could be represented as `char`, you could do `fwrite` a buffer with some `EOF`s in the middle. What would it do then?

Comment: @nigerianprince It was good to post input.  "should be 84 for this file, but it prints 87" was only describing output.  Posting your exact output and expected output is even more useful.

Comment: @EugeneSh. [re:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953672/reading-integers-from-a-text-file-and-adding-them-c/51954278#comment90858945_51953672)  If `EOF`, perhaps with a value of -1, and on a system where `char` is signed (quite common),  `char c = EOF; fwrite(&ch, 1, 1, file);` would simply write a character that a later `int d = fgetc()` would read as a value of 255.

Comment: @chux But what the dual `fread` will read? Anyway, why would the function write character `255`, when it is asked to write `EOF`? This doesn't make sense, so I would claim that `EOF` cannot be represented as `char` without breaking other things.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Using `fread()` of this 1 byte file --> `char c; size_t x = fread(&ch, 1, 1, file);` --> `c == -1, x == 1`.  Unclear what you mean by "dual" `fread()`.

Comment: @chux Yes, this is what I mean. But if `EOF` is `char` it should not read `-1`. It should encounter `EOF` instead and not read anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178469/discussion-between-chux-and-eugene-sh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... should I just change something in the code?

`while((c=fgetc(file))!=EOF)` does nothing with `c` and so loses a potential character of numeric input.

`if( fscanf(file, "%d", &number))` is a problem as is gets fooled when end-of-file occurs as `fscanf()` returned non-zero and so code thinks a number was read.

Instead try a 3-way branch.  Use the result value from `fscanf()` to guide the next steps.

```
int conversion_count;
do {
  conversion_count = fscanf(file, "%d", &number);
  if (conversion_count == 1) {
    // scanf() found an `int`
    printf("The number is %i\n  ", number);
    sum = sum + number;
  } else if (conversion_count == 0) {
    // scanf() failed to finf an `int`.
    // Offending non-numeric input remains in `file`.
    // Read non-numeric input character and quietly toss it.
    fgetc(file); // 
  }
} while (conversion_count != EOF);
```

Alternative: Robust code would read a line of text with `fgets()` and `strtol()` to look for integers.